# How can I make my MATLAB simulation code run more efficiently?

Tags: performance, matlab, simulation

I am creating a simulation to model a robot moving through river currents. The more code I add, the slower the simulation gets. Sometimes, it runs so slow that the buttons don't work. Does anyone know how I might speed it up?

It is possible that it might be my computer. A few times, the simulation ran flawlessly.

Code:

```
function CleanRiverSolutionsSimulation
%Initialize Figure
f = figure('Visible','off','Position',[250,250,1000,500],'Name','Clean River Solutions Simulation');

%Initialize variables (when changing these, don't forget to change them in
%the stop button function)
robot_position = [0 0 0];
last_robot_position = [-1 0 0];
time_data = [0];
depth_data = robot_position(3);
simulation_mode = 'paused'; %options: 'paused' 'running' 'stopped'
river_depth = 10;
water_flow_rate = 1;

%Initializes Plots
main_plot = axes('Units','pixels','Position',[50,225,500,250]);
data_plot1 = axes('Units','pixels','Position',[625,350,200,100]);

%Initializes Sliders
water_flow_slider = uicontrol('style','slider','position',[50 175 200 20],'min',0,'max',2.5,'callback',@callback_waterflow,'value',water_flow_rate);
water_flow_text = uicontrol('Style','text','String','River Water Flow','Position',[30 140 200 30]);
water_flow_text.String = sprintf('River Water Flow: %f m/s',get(water_flow_slider,'value'));
river_depth_slider = uicontrol('style','slider','position',[50 125 200 20],'min',0,'max',10,'callback',@callback_riverdepth,'value',river_depth);
river_depth_text = uicontrol('Style','text','String','River Depth','Position',[30 90 200 30]);
river_depth_text.String = sprintf('River Depth: %f m',get(river_depth_slider,'value'));

%Initializes Push Buttons
run_button = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Run','Position',[300 175 50 20],'callback',@callback_runbutton);
pause_button = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Pause','Position',[360 175 50 20],'callback',@callback_pausebutton);
stop_button = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Stop','Position',[420 175 50 20],'callback',@callback_stopbutton);
status_text = uicontrol('Style','text','String','Status','Position',[300 140 150 30]);
status_text.String = sprintf('Status: %s','Paused');

%After setup, makes figure visible
f.Visible = 'on';

%Environment Settings
riv_length = 20;
riv_width = 20;

%River flow settings
flow_dots = 4;

%Initialize Main Plot (when changing these, don't forget to change them in
%the stop button function)
plot3(main_plot,robot_position(1),robot_position(2),robot_position(3),'Marker', 'o','Color','r')
main_plot.XLim = [-riv_length/2 riv_length/2];
main_plot.YLim = [-riv_width/2 riv_width/2];
main_plot.ZLim = [-1*river_depth 1];
main_plot.XGrid = 'on';
main_plot.YGrid = 'on';
main_plot.ZGrid = 'on';

%Initialize time sequence (when changing these, don't forget to change them in
%the stop button function)
time = clock;
pausedStartTime = time(6)+60*time(5)+3600*time(4);
startTime = pausedStartTime;
pausedTime = 0;
totalPausedTime = 0;

%MAIN SIMULATION LOOP
while ishandle(f)
    switch simulation_mode
        case 'running'

            %TODO-add forces and have the positions depend on the forces

            %creates a time t to use in simulated equations
            time = clock;
            t = ((time(6)+60*time(5)+3600*time(4))-startTime-totalPausedTime);

            %X
            last_robot_position(1) = robot_position(1);
            robot_position(1) = 0;
            %Y
            last_robot_position(2) = robot_position(2);
            robot_position(2) = 0;
            %Z
            last_robot_position(3) = robot_position(3);
            robot_position(3) = -4+2*sin(2*t); %just did a sin wave to show movement

            %UPDATE MAIN PLOT
            %update robot position
            plot3(main_plot,robot_position(1),robot_position(2),robot_position(3),'Marker','o','Color','r')
            %update robot velocity vector?
            forward_vector = [robot_position(1)-last_robot_position(1),...
                              robot_position(2)-last_robot_position(2),...
                              robot_position(3)-last_robot_position(3)];
            forward_unit_vector = forward_vector./norm(forward_vector);
            hold(main_plot,'on')
            plot3(main_plot,[robot_position(1) (robot_position(1)+forward_unit_vector(1))],...
                            [robot_position(2) (robot_position(2)+forward_unit_vector(2))],...
                            [robot_position(3) (robot_position(3)+forward_unit_vector(3))]);
            %update river flow dots
            for dot = 1:flow_dots
                plot3(main_plot,-riv_length/2+(dot-1)*(riv_length/flow_dots)+mod((t/water_flow_rate),(riv_length/flow_dots)),10,0,'Marker','o','Color','b')
            end
            %update plot settings
            main_plot.XLim = [-riv_length/2 riv_length/2];
            main_plot.YLim = [-riv_width/2 riv_width/2];
            main_plot.ZLim = [-1*river_depth 1];
            main_plot.XGrid = 'on';
            main_plot.YGrid = 'on';
            main_plot.ZGrid = 'on';
            hold(main_plot,'off')

            %Update Data Plot 1 (depth)
            time = clock;
            time_data = [time_data ((time(6)+60*time(5)+3600*time(4))-startTime-totalPausedTime)];
            depth_data = [depth_data robot_position(3)];
            plot(data_plot1,time_data,depth_data)
            title('Robot Depth')
            data_plot1.XLim = [max(0,(((time(6)+60*time(5)+3600*time(4))-startTime-totalPausedTime)-15)),...
                               max(0,(((time(6)+60*time(5)+3600*time(4))-startTime-totalPausedTime)-15)+20)];
            data_plot1.YLim = [-1*river_depth 1];

            pause(0.1); %anything lower and the simulation won't pause

        case 'paused'

            pause(0.01); %need this or the sim won't start

        case 'stopped'         
            %so far, this line is never run
    end

end

    %executes callback for water flow slider
    function callback_waterflow(source,eventdata)
        water_flow_text.String = sprintf('River Water Flow: %f m/s',get(water_flow_slider,'value'));
        water_flow_rate = get(water_flow_slider,'value');
    end

    %executes callback for river depth slider
    function callback_riverdepth(source,eventdata)
        river_depth_text.String = sprintf('River Depth: %f m',get(river_depth_slider,'value'));
        river_depth = get(river_depth_slider,'value');
    end

    %executes callback for run button
    function callback_runbutton(source,eventdata)
        switch simulation_mode
            case 'stopped'
                %Reinitialize time sequence
                time = clock;
                startTime = time(6)+60*time(5)+3600*time(4);
                pausedTime = 0;
                totalpausedTime = 0;
            case 'paused'
                time = clock;
                currentTime = time(6)+60*time(5)+3600*time(4);
                pausedTime = currentTime-pausedStartTime;
                totalPausedTime = totalPausedTime + pausedTime;
                pausedTime = 0;
        end

        simulation_mode = 'running';
        status_text.String = sprintf('Status: %s','Running');
    end

    %executes callback for run button
    function callback_pausebutton(source,eventdata)
        switch simulation_mode
            case 'running'
                status_text.String = sprintf('Status: %s','Paused');
                time = clock;
                pausedStartTime = time(6)+60*time(5)+3600*time(4);
        end
        simulation_mode = 'paused';
    end

    %executes callback for run button
    function callback_stopbutton(source,eventdata)
        simulation_mode = 'stopped';
        status_text.String = sprintf('Status: %s','Stopping');

        %Reset all simulation data
        robot_position = [0 0 0];
        time_data = [0];
        depth_data = robot_position(3);

        %Reinitialize time sequence
        time = clock;
        pausedStartTime = time(6)+60*time(5)+3600*time(4);
        startTime = pausedStartTime;
        pausedTime = 0;
        totalPausedTime = 0;

        %Reinitialize Plots
        plot3(main_plot,robot_position(1),robot_position(2),robot_position(3),'Marker','o','Color','r')
        main_plot.XLim = [-riv_length/2 riv_length/2];
        main_plot.YLim = [-riv_width/2 riv_width/2];
        main_plot.ZLim = [-river_depth 1];
        plot(data_plot1,time_data,depth_data)

        status_text.String = sprintf('Status: %s','Data is reset.');
        simulation_mode = 'paused';
    end

end
```

Comment: You do a lot of plotting inside loops. Instead, do your computations and collect the results, then plot once at the very end. Or you can plot once every 100 time steps, or whatever number makes sense. Plotting is expensive!!!

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

matlab provides you tools to do this - it is called a profiler. try this

```
profiler on;
your_script_name;
profiler viewer;
```

from the output, you can tell which lines or functions cost most of your run time. I use it every time I need to speed up my matlab code.